# WSO2 Identity server 6.1.0 - External login page

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is it possible in WSO2 Identity server 6.1.0 to use a login page other than WSO2 IS default login page? I know that it can be customized, but can't it be an external login page? but in this case how to handle the other scenarios like reset password etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a readily available feature in IS.

This [post](https://medium.com/identity-beyond-borders/using-a-custom-login-page-for-wso2-identity-server-b8451b35cdd) provides step by step changes on how this can be implemented